# After boot from live CD, no usable desktop

Tags: 12.04, mac, live-cd

I have an old iMac G4 which I am trying to get Ubuntu installed on. I have a live CD and can boot from that. Everything loads and is running but there is some sort of graphical error and there is just a big white screen with a red bar on the left.

I'm pretty sure this is different from the other white screen of death I keep hearing about because I can still do some things. I can get to ctrl + alt + f1 and f2, the mouse works, there are options on the left in that red bar that i can click but not much happens when i do. I can click home dash and it brings up some icons in red color. I can not bring up the terminal.

I can click install ubuntu but I'm afraid that I will just install this problem permanently (right now I can still get to a working OSX 10.2)

I'm very new to linux but have tried a ton of different things online like reseting unity, trying to install drivers for nvidia, trying to bypass that welcome screen that i hear about but have not seen so far.

The computer runs from the cd, goes black for a long time, then the mouse appears for a long time, and then it goes to that white screen with the red bar. I never get any option to choose any thing or hit shift or esc like I have read.

I have pictures but it wont let me post them

Any advice?

memory: 1024 MB
Processor: 1.25 GHz
PowerPC G4
nvidia GeForce2 MX

Answer (score 0):

If it was me,  I would try a couple things:

- Try installing in parallel with your OSX partition. The Ubuntu installer will allow you to do this very easily. See if it actually installs with this error when you boot from the Ubuntu partition.
- If you don't see the problem,  just reinstall onto the whole disk and you'll be fine.  If you do,  make sure you have a good live disk (since you've tried installing drivers). Re-download it,  check the md5 checksum,  and try it again.

If neither of those work, only then would I go back and take a closer look at drivers and make sure I have the right ones installed. You'll need to install Ubuntu on your disk before installing drivers though. Installing them to a live disk won't do much good.

I hope that helps! 
-Ryan

Comment: well I messed around with enough stuff that compiz crashed. Once that happened I could then see the installer menu. So I guess that might mean that compiz was the causing the problems. 

However, when I installed there as no option for installing along side mac. All I had was over the top of OSX and something else. I clicked something else and it took me to the page with all the partitions. I read online how I'm supposed to partition but I dont have any free space. I tried to partition my main 80GB drive but when ever I go to disk utility in OSX all my buttons are greyed out.

Comment: I don't have enough experience with OSX to speak with any kind of authority, but can you run disk utility as "root" or administrator or whatever OSX calls the super user? That might unlock your buttons.  If you don't get anywhere with that,  you might also try making a GParted live cd and booting from that to edit your  partitions.  I could help with partitioning  too if you need it, but it sounds like you've found the info you need. http://gparted.org/download.php